# BufferReader buffer = new BufferReader() Gives me an ERROR NullPointerException and It stops there with Debug

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, httpclient, inputstreamreader

I tried running this code on Eclipse and it was me an error. I'm trying to send a HTTP to a php site and get the response as a TextView.

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        try{
            test_email = email.getText().toString();

            String submit = "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/httpget.php?user=" + test_email;

            URI websitetarget = new URI(submit);

            try{
                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet();
                httpget.setURI(websitetarget);
                HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpget);

                // get the message from the response 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if(entity == null){
                    content.setText("failed");  
                }

                InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
                InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(webs);

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

                // convert response to string 
                try{ 
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);

                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        str.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    str.toString();

                    content.setText(str);

                    webs.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    content.setText("failed");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                content.setText("FAIL");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            content.setText("FAIL");
        }
    }
});
```

Error I get in Logcat

```
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at com.example.login_test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:147)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17749)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
02-07 17:38:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(28709):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please mark line 147 in your code with a comment. Also, `str.toString()` is useless since you don't do anything with the returned String. What you really want is `content.setText(str.toString());`.

Comment: Thanks so much Axel, The error has disappeared !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above. Additionally, you will get `NullPointerException` if `entity==null` here:

```
            ...
            if(entity == null){
                content.setText("failed");  
            }

            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
            ...
```

This should be

```
            ...
            if(entity == null){
                content.setText("failed");  
                return;
            }

            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
            ...
```

Comment: OMG it worked, after all these hours spent !! Thanks heaps Axel, you're the best.   I always thought it was the BufferReader problem all along, Anyways cheers !